# How to figure what is blocking ports

Tags: networking, connection, internet-connection, window, ports

I have opened the follows ports in the router config

```
TCP 5242 4244
UDP 5243 9785
```

But these still remain unreachables. I have also tried to disable Comodo firewall without success.

Is there a way to understand what is blocking these ports?

I'm using windows 8.1 and a wifi connection.

Comment: Are you using Viber? http://www.viberfaq.com/why-cant-i-use-viber-on-some-wi-fi-networks/

Comment: @elhombre I'm trying to use Viber, but doesn't connect because of this issue.

Comment: If you could find out what the IP address of the server is which the viber software is connecting to, then it would be possible to check where the problem is. It's just a guess but you maybe wan't to check if your windows firewall is blocking the port http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-port-windows-firewall#1TC=windows-7

Comment: I have yet disabled also windows firewall, without success. How could I find what is the IP whrtr Viber connect?

Comment: The easiest way would be to ask viber for the server IP address. Could you also tell how you know that the ports don't work?

Comment: I have tried various port check services.